# Can my dog have a treat with medicine that she can only take on any empty stomach

Tags: dogs, medicines

Can I give my dog medicine with a little treat  even if it says take on any empty stomach?

Answer (score 4):

One treat still counts as "empty stomach", so yes. Especially if the dog refuses to take the medicine alone but does take it together with the treat, the benefits outweigh the negative effect one single treat can have.

However, you also need to wait a sufficient time after the last meal for the stomach to empty itself. Usually such medicine is best administered in the morning before the dog has breakfast.